# Showing a certain map is a group homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have an arbitrary ring $R$. Denote the direct sum of $R$ over some index set $I$ as $R^{(I)}$ and the direct product as $R^I$. The paper I am reading claims the following function is a  group homomorphism (article link listed below).

$\phi:R^I\rightarrow \text{Aut}((R\times R^{(I)},+)), b\mapsto ((r,a)\mapsto (r+\sum_{i\in I}a_ib_i, a))$

so I will say $\phi(b)=\alpha_b$ where $\alpha_b((r,a))=(r+\sum_{i\in I}a_ib_i, a)$

Indeed we have that these maps are automorphisms, but I can not convince myself that $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

This is what I get.

$\phi(b+b')=\alpha_{b+b'}$ and $\phi(b)+\phi(b')=\alpha_b+\alpha_{b'}$

but $\alpha_{b+b'}((r,a))=(r+\sum a_i(b_i+b_i'),a)=(r+\sum a_ib_i+\sum a_ib_i',a)$

and $\alpha_b((r,a))+\alpha_{b'}((r,a))=(r+\sum a_ib_i,a)+(r+\sum a_ib_i',a)=(2r+\sum a_ib_i+\sum a_ib_i',2a)$

Article link: https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/scripties/AponBach.pdf  (pg. 18 at the bottom)

Comment: I agree that the thing that you showed there doesn't look like a group homomorphism. Maybe he/she meant $\phi(b)$ is a homomorphism?(Probably, not but possible.)

Comment: As for inner products, I thought they were usually defined over vector spaces. I think the author means something like an inner product as defined at the beginning of the proof.

Comment: But what I don't get is how we can make sense of this sum if the index set $I$ is not a finite set unless there is some norm structure on $R$ to make sense of limits.

Comment: since (a) has only finite non zero, the sum will always be a finite sum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider composition as group operation on $\textrm{Aut}(R\times R^{(I)}, +)$ (instead of addition). So, we need
$$\phi(b+b') = \phi(b)\circ \phi(b'),$$
which is straightforward to check.

Comment: Wow, thanks! This happens to me a lot.